# Employee level vs Design/Tech Rating

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have sometimes come across situations where I had to fire an employee to hire a new one with better tech or design ratings and more research/speed points. However, since the earlier employee had been with the company for quite a while, the level of the employee was higher than the one I hired (say, level 6 against level 4).

Are there any specific weights given to the employee levels and design/tech ratings? If yes, which of them is more important?

(Assuming budget factor to be same.)

Comment: I don't think employee level affects anything except wages.  Be aware there is a ramp-up time for new employees.

Comment: But I have noticed sometimes a sort of drop in the new hire's contribution to the next game. Could that be because of the ramp up time you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_and_Design_Points_Generation_Algorithm) *and* the data I see in the save file, employee level is most definitely a factor -- their productive output is multiplied by 0.2 * employee level.

So a level 2 employee with the same tech/design stats as a level 4 employee will only produce half as many points.